# Calculate the direction (heading) in Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, map-directions

From origin to destination, I would like to know the direction of.

Simply want to know which direction is in the angle values​​.

In the image above, the angle value will be probably between 350-360.
(Image source : 
https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Dr+NS+Hardikar+Rd&daddr=Rithala+Metro+Station,+Rithala+Rd,+Sector+12,+Rohini,+New+Delhi,+Delhi,+India&geocode=FYfstQEdJn-YBA%3BFY8-tgEd3Y-YBCnlvvwRTAENOTHixeyZbhPwSA&sll=28.697665,77.11956&sspn=0.062715,0.11055&hl=en)

I can't upload image. sorry.

How do I calculate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#spherical) with `start_location` of the first `leg` and `end_location` of the last `leg` as arguments.

Comment: How would you do it if you needed to do it offline?

Comment: @Sidmeister: You'll find a nice library and descriptions at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html